# Can’t ping or mtr ipv4 when ufw enabled

Tags: networking, iptables

These don’t work when I have ufw enabled:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
mtr -n 8.8.8.8
```

Ping just hangs and the `mtr` command immediately spits out the confusing message, `mtr: Permission denied`.

IPv6 works fine:

```
ping 2001:4860:4860::8888
mtr -n 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

Everything works fine when I disable (service stop) `ufw`.

Here’s my ufw status:

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), deny (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    [REDACTED]
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    [REDACTED]

53                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
587                        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
33434:33524/udp            ALLOW OUT   Anywhere                  
53 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
587 (v6)                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)             
33434:33524/udp (v6)       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: @danorton ufw is just an dummy user interface for iptables. please check the default policy of the outgoing chain separatly for v4 and v6.  `ip6tables -n -v -L | grep "Chain OUTPUT"` and  `iptables -n -v -L | grep "Chain OUTPUT"` please add the output to your question.

Comment: @dummyuser both IPv4 and IPv6 commands report "Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP «nnn» packets, «nnn» bytes)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ping` uses ICMP which should be unaffected by `ufw` rules although there are ufw .rules files which may inhibit ICMP but these are rarely used.

There is on-line documentation explaining these.

This is a general Linux question, not Pi specific.

Comment: I see now that you’re right and I would have deleted this question, but it won’t let me because you answered. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ufw is a frontend for iptables and ip6tables. You will find some predefined rules in `/etc/ufw` (at ubuntu). There you will find some icmp rules for IPv6. ICMP is much more needed at IP v6 than in IPv4. This might be the reason for predefined rules.

If you really want to see all (filter) rules use `iptables -L -n -v` and `ip6tables -L -n -v`.